# How can I create dynamic variables using array values in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, variables, foreach

I'm trying to create dynamic variables using array value.
And getting this error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/transit_loss.php on line 674

```
<tr>
   <th>Bottles</th>

   <th><?php echo $quarter_months; ?>(<?php echo $quarter; ?>)</th>

   <th><?php echo $year; ?></th>
       <?php

          foreach ($tl_beer_columns_row as $columns) {

              foreach ($tl_beer_data as $key) {

        ?>

        <td><?php echo $key[$columns['COLUMN_NAME']]; ?></td>

            <?php

               $$columns['COLUMN_NAME'] = 0;
               print_r($$columns['COLUMN_NAME']);

               $$columns['COLUMN_NAME'] += key[$columns['COLUMN_NAME']];

            }

         }
      ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: **line 674** refers to which line in your code?

Comment: $$columns['COLUMN_NAME'] = 0;

Comment: It would probably be better to use arrays rather than using dynamic variables.

Comment: Yes @besciualex, thank you for this answer